# Write Parquet MAP datatype by PyArrow

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm writing in Python and would like to use PyArrow to generate Parquet files.

Per my understanding and [the Implementation Status](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/status.html), the C++ (Python) library already implemented the MAP type. From [the Data Types](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/datatypes.html), I can also find the type `map_(key_type, item_type[, keys_sorted])`.

So, I tested with several different approaches in Python/PyArrow. But all of them failed.

E.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': pd.Series([
            [('key', 'aaaa'), ('value', '1111')],
            [('key', 'bbbb'), ('value', '2222')],
        ]),
        'col2': pd.Series(['foo', 'bar'])
    }
)

udt = pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string())
schema = pa.schema([pa.field('col1', udt), pa.field('col2', pa.string())])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
pq.write_table(table, FILE_NAME)
```

When I read the file with `parquet-tools cat rand_gen_test_map.parquet`, I got:

```
col1:
.key_value:
.key_value:
col2 = foo

col1:
.key_value:
.key_value:
col2 = bar
```

It seems to me that the Map values are not outputted correctly (or missed). Though the schema is correct:

```
message schema {
  optional group col1 (MAP) {
    repeated group key_value {
      required binary key (UTF8);
      optional binary value (UTF8);
    }
  }
  optional binary col2 (UTF8);
}
```

All in all, I have two questions (all in Python):

1. what is the best way to generate Parquet files with MAP datatype (if will be great if an example can be attached)
2. I understand that we can use a `STRUCT` to mimic a map structure. But since Parquet provided the MAP type, we still want to use it. If the MAP data type can't be generated, what is the reason behind providing a MAP type?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in writing map types.  This should be fixed in pyarrow 2.0 (also reading is now supported natively)

Comment: thank you @micah-kornfield, the new version solved the issue for me indeed. much appreciated!

Comment: note there was also some bugs in 2.0 unfortunately, 3.0 hopefully has them all fixed.